MariaDB HEX() and UNHEX() missfunctioning?
According to the MariaDB manual at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unhex
SELECT HEX('MariaDB');
+----------------+
| HEX('MariaDB') |
+----------------+
| 4D617269614442 |
+----------------+

SELECT UNHEX('4D617269614442');
+-------------------------+
| UNHEX('4D617269614442') |
+-------------------------+
| MariaDB                 |
+-------------------------+

Unfortunatelly, not for me.
I'm running MariaDB 11.3.2 on Windows and I get the following result:
SELECT UNHEX('4D617269614442');
+-------------------------+
| UNHEX('4D617269614442') |
+-------------------------+
| 0x4d617269614442        |
+-------------------------+

Has anyone ever experienced this?
Do you know if I'm not noticing something obvious?
Or could it be a bug in this version on Windows?

Try one of their other examples like SELECT UNHEX(HEX('string'));

Given there's a significant number of UNHEX function calls tested in MariaDB's test machine, I'm thinking this is likely a client connection or terminal interface issue. Can you include \s information editing the question.

what exactly does select version(); show?

This seems to be a change in the 'definition' of what UNHEX() delivers.  In what way is it causing problems?  CAST(...) may help achieve your ultimate goal.

I had a colleague test this on 11.0 and 11.3 versions on Windows and couldn't reproduce this.

my theory is they are giving us a client version, not a server version, and we need to know what the server is first.
